# Identifying Coordinate Mapping

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a dataset with a linestring containing coordinates like: `376753.328, 2042051.611` I've tried unpacking using a couple different coordinate mappings to get the GPS coordinates. I'm told the coordinates are in India and I have a projection of `EPSG:3857`. I'm using primarily geopandas but use QGIS too. What else is needed to figure how to translate these into a more commonly recognized coordinate mapping

Comment: Derek, the easiest is to ask the person who gave you the data to start with. Could you share which software you are using for the task?

Comment: You only provided with so little information regarding the issue that you face. I can only say the coordinate should be in x, y because you use EPSG:3857

Comment: Those numbers are common for UTM, try to find what zone they are. For instance, for zone 44N, see: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeoConvert?input=44n+376753.328+2042051.611&zone=-3&prec=0&option=Submit

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I'll start looking there. I'm using Geopandas and QGIS

Comment: Your coordinate of 376753.328, 2042051.611 is typically a UTM coordinate. A ballpark long lat can be obtained by dividing by 111120 meters per degree: 3.3°E 18.4°N

Comment: For the correct longitude add (UTMzone-30.5)*6. EPSG:3857.is not correct.

Comment: Yeah, I've realized the error of the projection. The UTM values fit for Zone 44Q - Thanks Gabriel De Luca!